# What is the likelihood of an observed standard deviation given a known normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, likelihood

Given a sample X of size n from a normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma)$ one can estimate $\sigma$ by $\hat{\sigma}$ from X. Then we know that:

$p(\sigma|\hat{\sigma},n)\propto\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{\chi^2(\nu=n-1)}}$

Now I am looking for the likelihood function: $p(\hat{\sigma}|\sigma,n)$.

Is there an analytic solution for this or is it necessary to derive the likelihood function from case-by-case simulations?

Can someone help me with this relation? Or better, point to a reference where this relation has been used before?

Comment: Because it is unnecessary to consider $\sigma$ to be a random variable, your first formula is irrelevant. To get your bearings, take a look at the [$\chi$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution).

Comment: @whuber [WolframMathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html) seems to describe the answer. The distribution of the sample standard deviation is indeed closely related to the chi-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframMathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html) does provide the likelihood function $p(\hat{\sigma}|\sigma,n)$.

I confirmed the validity of this answer by simple Monte Carlo simulation.